# How to block transformations on UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, transformation

I have a problem with a UIView, hope you can help me.

I have a UIView A that contains some subview (B and C) and I have to use a transformation 3D on **A** (that will transform **B** and **C** also). It is possible to block the transformation B, so the transformation will be performed only on A and C?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redo the transformation in opposite direction to nullify the transformation effect. For example,

```
 for (UIView *subview in [myview subviews]) 
 {
    if(subview is B) //Pseudo code
    subview.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(yourTransform);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably not. when you transform the superview A you transform all subviews and so B and C are  rendered in the transformed A plane. So you cannot transform subviews B, C outside of A plane.
You could just move B and C outside of A subviews and let them be subviews of A superview, then manage on them the same transformation of A (or not in case of B), but then you should be careful to manage their positions after the transformations...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is correct but Vignesh's answer resolve my problem also :)